# Validate the user input against a specific pattern BASH

Tags: bash, regular-expression, csh

```
if ($input !~ [[:upper:-]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:-]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]) then
   goto error1
else
   echo $input
endif
```

I have tried the above code to match the pattern "P-70-90" but it didn't work.

I am trying it in cShell but bash format can also be implemented.

Comment: I suspect the "upper" class is wrongly interpreted because the - messes the class name. This possibly ought to be [[:upper:]-]. It's been 2**5 years since I used csh.

Comment: please provide "input" that you would like to match against

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally found solution:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash

REGEX='^[[:upper:]]-([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{3})-([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{3})$'

CHECK="P-70-56"

if [[ ! $CHECK =~ $REGEX ]]
then
    echo "Not ok"
else 
    echo "ok"
fi
```

Comment: **^[[:upper:]]-([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{3})-([0-9]{2}I[0-91{3})$** do not match neither **P-70-90** nor **P-70-56**

Comment: @Archemar I guess that the simpler `REGEX='^[[:upper:]]-[0-9]{2,3}-[0-9]{2,3}$'` will also work as intended.

Comment: Thanks mosvy ; it worked.